# Why is "Jingle Bell Rock" but not "Jingle Bell Rocks"?

Tags: lyrics

The lyrics of Jingle Bell Rock goes:

> Jingle bell, jingle bell, jingle bell rock
> Jingle bells swing and jingle bells ring...

I wonder why the '**bell**' in '***Jingle bell rock***' is singular yet it's '**rock**' and not '**rocks**'.

And then why is '*Jingle **bells swing***' not '*Jingle **bell ring***' or '*Jingle **bell rings***'?

Any reason why are the singularity and plurality inconsistent?

Comment: They're poets they've got especially no reason/grammar to write ◠‿◕.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jingle-bell is a compound noun, it can be plural or singular.

In the first phrase you have a noun "rock" being modified by an adjunct noun "jingle-bell". "Jingle-bell rock" isn't a sentence, nor is it a clause, as there is no verb. It is a headline meaning "This is 'jingle-bell' rock(-and-roll)"

The second line then uses "subject verb" sentences, with plural subject "jingle-bells" and a verb in simple present "ring".

We tend to use singular for noun adjuncts, for example, "chicken soup" not "chickens soup".

Here is a song by me

*Chicken soup, chicken soup

Chickens go in the pot

For my chicken soup.*

*My chicken runs away

From me today

'Cos I want some chicken soup!*

That isn't a great song... but notice that "chicken soup" is a singular noun-noun phrase, not a "subject verb" clause. But "Chickens go" and "my chicken runs" are both examples of "subject-verb". This is the same as "jingle-bell rock"

Comment: Nice song! Is it available on iTunes?  ;-)

Comment: Still working on the melody

Comment: You never know, it could rival Baby Shark! (doo doo ta doo-doo do)

Comment: Thank you very much! I am both educated and entertained XD

Answer (score 5):

I think you're assuming that **'rock'** is synonymous with **'swing'** which, in some contexts, are i.e., both can mean ***to sway from side to side***.

However, both **'rock'** and **'swing'** are names for genres of music. We don't pluralise these - for example:

> "I like rock music"

It means that you like lots of different music that falls under that genre.

I believe the title of the song *'Jingle Bell Rock'* is a reference to rock music, based on the fact that the lyrics refer to another song *'Rock around the Clock'*. It would seem that the line **"jingle bell rock"** is referring to the music, while the lines in which the bells (plural) **'swing'** and **'ring'**, is a description of bells actually ringing.

Comment: +1: this should be the accepted answer, since it directly addresses the key point that "rock" here is a noun (the genre) rather than a verb.

Comment: When you think about it in what way is rock music like stones? Unless you're talking about one of the several rock groups with stone in their names.